# Successive over-relaxation formation of heat equation?

Tags: pde, finite-difference

What is the form of [SOR iterative equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) for the heat equation
$u_{xx}=u_{t}-1$ using centered differences both in time and spatial
derivatives and using [Crank-Nicolson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method)?

$$(u(x,0)=u(L,t)=u(0,t)=A;0<x<L,0<t<\infty)$$

Can anyone help me to obtain the SOR iterative equation?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: It was also posted on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106580/equation-of-sor-itterative-method) earlier.

Comment: I think SOR equation using centered differences by crank-nikolson
method is obtained as follows:
$u_{i,j}=\frac{1}{2\alpha}[1+\alpha u_{i-1,j+1}-(1+2\alpha)
u_{i,j+1}-\alpha u_{i+1,j+1}+\alpha u_{i+1,j}+\alpha u_{i-1,j}+\alpha
u_{i,j-1}]$
where $\alpha=\frac{\delta t}{\delta x^{2}}$. But I don't know how can
obtain sor iterative eqution from this?

Comment: @juing: Can you show the steps you used to arrive at this equation?  It will help to us to verify whether it's correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the time index is $j$, you can obtain the SOR iteration by solving your iteration for $u_{i,j+1}$.  Then you can iterate as:

$u_{i,j+1}^{N+1}=\omega (U_{i,j}^{gs})^{N+1} +(1-\omega)(U_{i,j}^{prev})^{N}$

where $(U_{i,j}^{gs})^{N+1}$ is the gauss-seidel value obtained on the current iteration, and $(U_{i,j}^{prev})^{N}$ is the value obtained from the previous iteration.

Comment: Why did you consider the SOR iteration for $u_{i,j+1}$ instead of $u_{ij}$?
and the equivalence of $ (U_{i,j}^{gs})^{N+1}$ is:
$(u_{i,j}^{gs})^{N+1}=$$$\frac{1}{2\alpha}[1+\alpha (u_{i-1,j+1})^{N}-(1+2\alpha)
(u_{i,j+1})^{N}-\alpha (u_{i+1,j+1})^{N}+\alpha (u_{i+1,j})^{N}+\alpha u_{i-1,j}^{N+1}+\alpha
(u_{i,j-1})^{N+1}]$$
Am I right about the current iteration and previous iteration signs?

Comment: Assuming j is the time index, then $u_{i,j}$ is already known, but $u_{i,j+1}$ is unknown.